# SQL statement not inserting data into database

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-insert

Basically what I'm trying to do is to get a user to submit his/her order into my database through a form. I can grab the c_id (customer_id) from a php code at the top of the page so there's nothing wrong there.

This is my html for my form.

```
                       <form action="tshirtorder.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><!-- form Begin -->

                        <div class="form-group"><!-- form-group Begin -->

                           <label>Design Image</label>

                           <input type="file" name="t_image" class="form-control form-height-custom" required>
                       </div>
                       <div class="form-group"><!-- form-group Begin -->

                           <label>Design Name</label>

                           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="t_name" value="Custom Design" disabled>

                       </div><!-- form-group Finish -->

                       <div class="form-group"><!-- form-group Begin -->

                           <label>Quantity</label>

                           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="t_qty" required>

                       </div><!-- form-group Finish -->

                       <div class="form-group"><!-- form-group Begin -->

                           <label>Size</label>

                           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="t_size" required>

                       </div><!-- form-group Finish -->


                       <div class="text-center"><!-- text-center Begin -->

                          <a href="torder.php?c_id=<?php echo $customer_id ?>"><button type="submit" name="tsubmit" class="btn btn-primary">

                           <i class="fa fa-user-md"></i> Send Message

                              </button></a>

                       </div><!-- text-center Finish -->

                   </form><!-- form Finish -->
```

Below is my sql statement.

```
<?php
```

if(isset($_POST['tsubmit'])){

```
$customer_id = $_GET['c_id'];

$t_image = $_FILES['t_image']['name'];

$t_image_tmp = $_FILES['t_image']['tmp_name'];

$t_name = $_POST['t_name'];

$due_amount = "25";

$invoice_no = mt_rand();

$t_qty = $_POST['t_qty'];

$t_size = $_POST['t_size'];

$status = "pending";

$pro_id = "$customer_id + 1";

move_uploaded_file($t_image_tmp,"images/customer/customerdesign/$t_image");

$sub_total = "$t_qty*25";

$insert_tshirt_order = "insert into tshirt_orders (customer_id,due_amount,invoice_no,qty,size,order_date,order_status) values ('$customer_id','$sub_total','$invoice_no','$t_qty','$t_size',NOW(),'$status')";

$run_tshirt_order = mysqli_query($conn,$insert_tshirt_order);

$insert_tpending_order = "insert into tpending_order (customer_id,invoice_no,product_id,qty,size,order_status) values ('$customer_id','$invoice_no','$pro_id','$t_qty','$t_size','$status')";

$run_tpending_order = mysqli_query($conn,$insert_tpending_order);


echo "<script>alert('Your T-Shirt Design has been successfully ordered!')</script>";

echo "<script>window.open('profile.php?t_orders','_self')</script>";

}
```

?>

There are a few attributes in my sql statement that I wish to be added automatically into my database such as the sub total price for the item and the invoice num, date and status.

For some reason, it's just not inserting the values into the database and I've ran through the statement for quite some time now and I can't figure out what is wrong. Hoping to find an answer here. Thank you.

Comment: Please invest some time to learn about [prepared statements in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Check the value of `$run_tshirt_order` and `$run_tpending_order`, if they are false, output the value of `mysqli_error($conn)`

Comment: Why do you have two tables containing the same data? Which insert fails?

Comment: The two tables are for different uses. customer_orders is for customers to view their orders, pending_orders are for the admins to check in admin panel. Both the insert statements fail and or (mysqli_error($conn) isn't showing any errors. Even tried or die(mysqli_error($conn))

Answer (score 1):

[mysqli_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) returns a boolean response, meaning you should listen to it, in case something is wrong with your SQL code.

Instead of `$run_tshirt_order = mysqli_query($conn,$insert_tshirt_order);`  try the following:

```
if(!$run_tshirt_order = mysqli_query($conn,$insert_tshirt_order)){
    //If the query returns a boolean FALSE
    die(mysqli_error($conn));
    //die() simply kills the script and outputs a message
    //You should replace it with better error handling
}
```

That way, if there is ever an error in your SQL, you'll be told about it.
If you can figure out what the error is from the error message, paste the results in your question so that we can have a look.

Comment: Add the format to both your SQL queries (`mysqli_query($conn,$insert_tpending_order);` also). Still no error?

Comment: If that doesn't work, do a var_dump() of your SQL query, and see if it even contains the values you want to insert.

Comment: I recoded the insert statement and decided to test each column so now I manually insert all the records through the form, customer_id included.. I'm able to insert the records without t_name and t_image. I can't insert into the database when they are in the query.. But when I remove t_name and t_image, I'm able to insert them.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. I recoded the entire sql statement. To anyone who's having the same problem as I did, here's my recoded code, maybe you can work something out from mine :)

```
    <?php
```

if(isset($_POST['tsubmit'])){

```
$session_name = $_SESSION['customer_name'];

$select_customer = "select * from customers where customer_name='$session_name'";

$run_customer = mysqli_query($conn,$select_customer);

$row_customer=mysqli_fetch_array($run_customer);

$customer_id= $row_customer['customer_id'];

$t_name = $_POST['t_name'];

$due_amount = 25;

$invoice_no = mt_rand();

$t_qty = $_POST['t_qty'];

$t_size = $_POST['t_size'];

$t_image = $_FILES['t_image']['name'];

$t_image_tmp = $_FILES['t_image']['tmp_name'];

$status = "pending";

$total_amount = $due_amount*$t_qty;

$pro_id = $customer_id + 1;

move_uploaded_file($t_image_tmp,"images/customer/customerdesign/$t_image");

$insert_tshirt_order = "insert into tshirt_orders (customer_id,t_image,t_name,due_amount,invoice_no,qty,size,order_date,order_status) values ('$customer_id','$t_image','$t_name','$total_amount','$invoice_no','$t_qty','$t_size',NOW(),'$status')";

$run_tshirt_order = mysqli_query($conn,$insert_tshirt_order);

$insert_tpending_order = "insert into tpending_order (customer_id,invoice_no,product_id,qty,size,order_status) values ('$customer_id','$invoice_no','$pro_id','$t_qty','$t_size','$status')";

$run_tpending_order = mysqli_query($conn,$insert_tpending_order);

    echo "<script>alert('Your T-Shirt order has been made!')</script>";  
        echo "<script>window.open('profile.php?t_orders','_self')</script>";

}
```

?>

Also, a big thank you to the people who tried to help me! I appreciate it alot.